# Creating framework in XCode

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, dylib, xcode, ios-frameworks

I am creating a framework in XCode 4. I made this header public (SkypeListener.h):

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <Skype/Skype.h>

void start();
void stop();


@interface SkypeListener : NSObject <SkypeAPIDelegate>

- (void)start;
- (void)stop;

@end
```

The framework is called SkypeTestFramework. Now to test this framework and I setup a new project, dragged SkypeTestFramework into the frameworks folder and imported:

```
#import <SkypeTestFramework/SkypeListener.h>
```

But I get this error:

```
/Users/****/Desktop/testskype/SkypeTestFramework.framework/Headers/SkypeListener.h:10:9: fatal error: 'Skype/Skype.h' file not found [1]
```

What am I doing wrong? Thanks.

Oh also, in SkypeTestFramework, I am using a framework called Skype.framework. Could it be that, that's causing the problem?
Thanks.

Comment: Where is Skype/Skype.h ?

Comment: copy your framework into your project folder then add your framework from that location.try this.

Comment: Asisih, I did that and now I get this:
dyld: Library not loaded: /Library/Frameworks/TestFramework.framework/Versions/A/SkypeTestFramework
  Referenced from: /Users/muhammadahmed/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/testskype-bchhhqwihaugdvcrhdrnwnbebbsk/Build/Products/Debug/testskype.app/Contents/MacOS/testskype
  Reason: image not found

Answer (score 0):

If you created `Skype/Skype.h`, would write it like:  `import "Skype/Skype.h"`.  But you would need to include the full path if it not part of your current project.

Comment: I didn't create Skype framework. It's the official framework from Skype (it can be found in Skype app bundle). Can you please tell me where I need to include this path and can I just bundle it with the framework so all I need to do is import #import <SkypeTestFramework/SkypeListener.h>
 and call start() / stop() ? is it possible?

Comment: @RungaDeMungoezz  Where Skype.h located?  Frameworks provided by Apple are located at "/usr/include" or "/System/Library/Frameworks," plus a couple others I think.  That would be the standard include path used by XCode.  Could you provide a download link to the bundle you mentioned?

Comment: I have uploaded the framework i created here: http://www.fileserve.com/file/pJXv8dE/TestFramework.zip
It includes the Skype framework with it. This is the framework that I am trying to use. If you want me to upload it to some other host, let me know. Thanks!!!

Comment: Ok I figuered out something. I need to add "@executable_path/../Frameworks" in the Installation directory. After doing that, the error "image not found" is not for the framework i created any more but rather the Skype framework. So I added Skype to my copy files build phase. But the error still remains...any idea? THANKS!

Comment: @RungaDeMungoezz  I there is a folder missing somewhere in your framework.

Answer (score 0):

The Skype.framework provided by Skype is incompatible with Xcode 4.1.  In fact, it's of PPC arche

Answer (score 0):

You can get new Skype.framework from Skype.app